# An Internet Phenomenon

Tags: riddle, haiku

> I am on the internet.
>   Others use me to troll.
>   There are many things I will never do.

What am I?

Hint:

> I only show up on the internet. Nowhere else. Not even in your mail.

Hint 2:

> I am a video.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's:

> Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up

I am on the internet

> Right here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Others use me to troll

> If you've been living in the cave for the last decade, see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rickrolling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

There are many things I will never do

> Some examples of things he'll never do are giving you up, letting you down, running around, deserting you, making you cry, saying goodbye, telling a lie, and hurting you.

Comment: You did it! YAY!

Comment: @feelinferrety: +1 for the edit

Answer (score 1):

Is it:

> Spam

On the internet

> Spam is usually found on the Internet

Others use me to troll lol

> Spam can also be used in random websites to annoy people or can "spam" stuff to other people as a troll

Never do much things

> Spam doesn't really do much... it is just an advertisement that is most likely unneeded

Comment: That isn't the answer I intended, but it's a good one!